# Create a UIImage programmatically with multiple fill colors

Tags: objective-c

I know how to create a UIImage programatically, with the following code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What I want to do is, to fill it with multiple colors. like the following

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know how to paint one rectangle, just extrapolate for painting multiple rectangles as below. Usse your own colors. I have used inbuilt color, if need any custom colors then set the color using RGB value.

```
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f);

        NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor brownColor],
                                [UIColor lightGrayColor],nil];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        for (int i = 0; i < colorArray.count; i++)
        {
            CGRect smallRect = CGRectMake((300.0f /colorArray.count) * i,0.0f,(300.0f /colorArray.count) ,60.0f);
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [colorArray[i] CGColor]);
            CGContextFillRect(context, smallRect);
        }


        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```